# How can I extract multiple .zip files?

Tags: python, zip, data-extraction

I'm trying to extract multiple files from some .zip archives. My code is:

```
import os
import zipfile

os.chdir('/home/marlon/Shift One/Projeto Philips/Consolidação de Arquivos')

for f in os.listdir("/home/marlon/Shift One/Projeto Philips/Consolidação de Arquivos"):
    if f.endswith(".zip"):
        z = zipfile.ZipFile(f, 'r')
        z.extractall(path = '/home/marlon/Shift One/Projeto Philips/Consolidação de Arquivos/dados')
        z.close()
```

However, it only extracts the files inside the first archive. I'm using Python 3.6. What is wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unzip all zipped files in a folder to that same folder using Python 2.7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31346790/unzip-all-zipped-files-in-a-folder-to-that-same-folder-using-python-2-7-5)

Comment: @aaz I'm using Python 3.6

Comment: do you get error message ? If you get error then add it in question (not in comment). First you could use `print()` to check values in `f` - maybe files have extension '.ZIP' instead of `.zip`. You can also check if code inside `if` statement is executed. You can also check if files inside .zip files have different names - it may ovewrite one file with another.

Comment: @furas no error message. I printed it and it just out put one .zip archive. There are nine of them.

Comment: do you use `print()` before `if f.endswith(".zip"):` or inside `if f.endswith(".zip"):` ? if you get one file before `if f.endswith(".zip"):` then it seems there is only one file in folder. If you get one file inside `if f.endswith(".zip"):` then maybe they don't have extensions `.zip` but `.ZIP` or there is space at the end of `.zip `.

Comment: @furas when I print it just before `if f.endswith(".zip"):` I get every thing inside the folder including the 9 .zip archives. Printing after the whole gives me only one archive. Running the code with .ZIP doesn't do anything.

Comment: so it seems your files may have some space in extension - `".zip "`. You will no see space when you print it but for Python it is not `".zip"`. You can `print(f + "<")` to see if there is space before `<`. OR you have other char which is not printed - ie. `tab`.

Comment: OR maybe you have files with extensions like `.Zip` - for Linux and Python (and any other programming language and program) it is different extension than `.zip` and `.ZIP`. You would have to check `f.lower().endswith(".zip")`

Comment: Thanks @furas. Appreciate it. I’ll check it out!

Comment: Do your archives contain files having same names? This is one situation that could lead to your scenario.

Comment: @CristiFati that is the case. Sorry, I’ve read quickly your comment and I thought you’ve meant “all the archives have the same names”. All the files inside the multiples .zip archives have the same name.

Comment: If all the archives would have the same name, then they couldn't be more than one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought this scenario might be a serious candidate ...

What happens is that for each *.zip* file, all its members are extracted, but they overwrite the ones extracted from the previous file (well, except the 1<sup>st</sup>). So, at the end, you end up with the files from the last archive that was enumerated. 
To get past this issue, you should unzip each *.zip* file members in a separate directory (the *.zip* file name).

Below is an example (I also simplified / cleaned your code a bit).

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import glob
import zipfile


dir_name_base = r"/home/marlon/Shift One/Projeto Philips/Consolidação de Arquivos"

for arc_name in glob.iglob(os.path.join(dir_name_base, "*.zip")):
    arc_dir_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(arc_name))[0]
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(arc_name)
    zf.extractall(path=os.path.join(dir_name_base, "dados", arc_dir_name))
    zf.close()  # Close file after extraction is completed
```

Comment: I'd say you were not quite so far, after all you managed to enumerate the archives and extract their content.... it just happened that the content was the same :)

Comment: let me ask you something. I’m a beginner, as you’ve seen probably. What’s the meaning of “[0]”? Thanks

Comment: It's the 1st element of the list (sequence). Try playing in the *Python* console: `os.path.splitext("file.txt")`, then `os.path.splitext("file.txt")[0]`, you'll see what I mean (you have to `import os` first).