# Unzipping multiple file without loosing the original creation date

Tags: python, unzip

I'm unzipping hundreds of zipped files with python as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69101930/10286584).

```
import os
import zipfile

base_dir = '/users/me/myFile' # absolute path to the data folder
extension = ".zip"

os.chdir(base_dir)  # change directory from working dir to dir with files


def unpack_all_in_dir(_dir):
    for item in os.listdir(_dir):  # loop through items in dir
        abs_path = os.path.join(_dir, item)  # absolute path of dir or file
        if item.endswith(extension):  # check for ".zip" extension
            file_name = os.path.abspath(abs_path)  # get full path of file
            zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(file_name)  # create zipfile object
            zip_ref.extractall(_dir)  # extract file to dir
            zip_ref.close()  # close file
        elif os.path.isdir(abs_path):
            unpack_all_in_dir(abs_path)  # recurse this function with inner folder


unpack_all_in_dir(base_dir)
```

When I unzip a file manually it will get its original modification date, whereas when doing it with code I loose this - the modification date turns into now's date.

Any idea of a way the preserve the original creation date?

[image]

Comment: please add code samples here, and 2-3 reference .osm files for us to recreate the issue.

Comment: does this help? from what @Expurple wrote it seems this a challenge with all types of files, not only OSM

Comment: Yes you are right, The thread shared by Expurple it's 5 years old and there are no changes made in the zip file implementation. You will have to hack around. The thread has working solutions that you can refer to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually opening multiple zip files manually keeps the dates, at least on macOS.
Search for the files you need to unzip, select -> open.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know `zipfile` very well, but according to [this thread about modification date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813243/extract-files-from-zip-file-and-retain-mod-date), preserving metadata is a pain.

You can hack around with calling some CLI archiving program as a subprocess, but you need to make sure that it's installed on the target system. I actually had to bundle 7zip with my script once, because of some issue with Python libraries, even third-party ones

Comment: It's not that painful.